# Why is this ComboBox data binding not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a small test window, like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" DisplayMemberPath="Word" ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Numbers = new ObservableCollection<NumberWord>
                      {
                          new NumberWord {Number = 1, Word = "One"},
                          new NumberWord {Number = 2, Word = "Two"},
                          new NumberWord {Number = 3, Word = "Three"}
                      };
        Combo.ItemsSource = Numbers;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<NumberWord> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

I keep seeing answers to my other binding questions that state the explicit setting of `Combo.ItemsSource = Numbers;` is unnecessary because I have the binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}"`. I have also been told multiple times that I need not set a `DataContext` on `Combo` because the whole window is the data context, and `Combo` inherits this data context.

My question is, why do I always - not just this combo - set `ItemsSource` or other binding properties explicitly in code behind. Why is the XAML data binding not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataContext` is one of the `DependancyProperties` which the child control inherits from the Parent if the local value is not set.

Hence if you set the `DataContext` of `Window` to something, the child controls including your `ComboBox` will have it.

Now, in your case, you have not set the `DataContext` of your `Window` hence your `Binding` of `ItemsSource` is not working

If in the constructor of your window, after initializeComponent you do

```
DataContext = this;
```

then you need not to set the `ItemsSource` of `Combobox` in `code behind` and your binding of `ItemsSource` will work on your Combo.

Answer (score 2):

The binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}"` needs a source object, namely one that has a public `Numbers` property. In your case this is the MainWindow instance.

So either you set the source explicitly by something like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

or you set the source object by setting a `DataContext`, e.g. in code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    ...
}
```

In case you need to change the value of the `Numbers` property later, you also have to add a property change notification mechanism, like implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

---

This is all well explained in the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. then use:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: I don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` because nothing is changing, and `Numbers` is but one member of the data context, so it would be stupid of me to set `DataContext = Numbers`. Other controls will share this data context and want to bind to members other than `Numbers`.

Comment: @ProfK: You Right , maybe best option is using MVVM for multiple controls and single datacontext. sorry, i corrected changed answer to this.DataContext = this;